# Tableview embedded in a container view resets data when orientation is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a **Tableview** embedded in a **containerview**. The table view has one section when loaded and user can mark the cells as completed which will move them to the section completed. My problem is after i have moved one cell to completed section if i change the orientation, the cell comes back to its original position and the completed section is empty. It changes the orientation and resizes all labels and images inside the cell though.How can i have the tableview change orientation with data in both sections?
This is how i load the embedded tableviewcontroller,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"embedPickListSegue"]) {

    TasksTableViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
//this array is used to create the tableview
viewController.tasks = self.tasks;
}
```

Then in the TasksTableViewController,when user selects complete,

```
[self.tasks removeObject:task];
NSIndexPath *removeIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];

[self.complete insertObject:task atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *insertIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[removeIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[insertIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Is there some code you could show us (perhaps the data source of the table)?

Comment: I use the embed segue to embed the tableview controller, PickTasksTableViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

Comment: Where does the table get the data (the text that's written in the cells, for instance)?

Comment: I pass it from the prepareForSegue:sender. It is an array,                        viewcontroller.tasks=self.tasks;

Comment: So, when the cells are moved, does your data source (`self.tasks`) change at all? The table reloads its data when the orientation changes.

Comment: i maintain separate arrays for each section. There is another array completed tasks which maintains cells in new section

Comment: This would be much simpler to answer if you included some source code in your question. Consider a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially if you (for whatever reason) don't want to copy and paste your code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I used global arrays for available and completed tasks to load the table from and it solved the issue. Both arrays i was using was getting reinitialized on orientation change.